# Sort array of points by ascending distance from given

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need your help!
I have a point with known coordinates, like `{x:5, y:4}` and array of objects each representing points:

```
[{x:2,y:6},{x:14,y:10},{x:7,y:10},{x:11,y:6},{x:6,y:2}]
```

Now I need to sort the array by distance from the given point in ascending order, like:

```
[{x: 6, y: 2}, {x: 2, y: 6}, {x: 7, y: 10}, {x: 11, y: 6}, {x: 14, y: 10}]
```

How can I don that with JS???
Thanks!

Comment: There is good information in the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) documentation

Comment: What is given point in above case?

Comment: How do you calculate the distance?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think, that might work:

```js
//reference point
const a = {x:5,y:4};
//array of points to sort
const points = [{x:2,y:6},{x:14,y:10},{x:7,y:10},{x:11,y:6},{x:6,y:2}];
//squared distance
const sqDist = (pointa, pointb) => (pointa.x-pointb.x)**2+(pointa.y-pointb.y)**2;
//sorting
const res = points.sort((pointa, pointb) => sqDist(a,pointa)-sqDist(a,pointb));

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: first, get `const dist` out of the compare function. You don't need to define this function for every single comparison. Second if `distanceA > distanceB` then so is `distanceA**2 > distanceB**2`. `Math.sqrt()` is an expensive operation and can be omitted here.

Comment: @Thomas : I have done it exactly the way math formula suggests, I agree, though, certain optimization can be done for the sake of performance

Answer (score 3):

This is a slightly shorter version without using `Math.sqrt`, because it uses the quadratic sum of the deltas.

```js
const
   array = [{ x: 2, y: 6 }, { x: 14, y: 10 }, { x: 7, y: 10 }, { x: 11, y: 6 }, { x: 6, y: 2 }],
   point = { x: 5, y: 4 };

array.sort((a, b) =>
    (a.x - point.x) ** 2 + (a.y - point.y) ** 2 -
    (b.x - point.x) ** 2 + (b.y - point.y) ** 2
);

console.log(array)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: `Math.abs((a.x - point.x) * (a.y - point.y)) - Math.abs((b.x - point.x) * (b.y - point.y))` because negative products don't mean negative distance.

Comment: For the array `[{ x: 2, y: 2 }, { x: 0, y: 0 }, { x: -2, y: -2 }, { x: -1, y: 1 }, { x: 1, y: -1 }]` and point `{ x: 1, y: 1 }` it returns wrong result. You, most probably, need to enclose each delta into `Math.abs()` as well, which will make that approach not very short.

Comment: @U25lYWt5IEJhc3RhcmQg, you are right, please see edit.

Comment: @NinaScholz : and now that's nothing different from my answer :)